# Proguard Obfuscation in eclipse

Tags: android, obfuscation

I want to obfuscate my android project.I watched a lot of tutorials but they didn't help me and I was not able to obfuscate my app.I have included the proguard folder in my project but it is not obfuscating my code.

Comment: Normally all that is needed is setting minifyEnabled to true in your build.gradle file (app level). Make sure you generate a non-debuggable app. Build a release version. (assuming you are using proguard)

Comment: i m using eclipse if possible than tell me something for eclipse

Answer (score 1):

try this....

In eclipse package explorer go to your project and open project.properties file.
In this file uncomment the below line

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

Open proguard-project.txt and paste

```
-injars      bin/classes
-injars      libs
-outjars     bin/classes-processed.jar
-libraryjars C:\.....sdk/platforms/android-20/android.jar

-dontpreverify
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

And finally right click on your project folder --> Android Tools --> Export Signed Application Package

Check the exported .apk !!

Comment: it is working but still it is not obfuscating my project classes